# Searching Inside an Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

If I have a bucket with hundreds of thousands of images, is it ok to have to search for each image I want to display in my site via it's ID or is there a more efficient way (including having multiple folders in a bucket maybe)?

I was also thinking of giving each image a unique hash or something similar in order to stop duplicated names in the bucket. Does that seem like a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You just link to each image using normal urls. for public files the urls are in the format:

```
http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myimage.jpg
```

For private urls, you need to generate a url (which is easy using any of the sdks) in the format:

```
http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myimage.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=44CF9SAMPLEF252F707&Expires=1177363698&Signature=vjSAMPLENmGa%2ByT272YEAiv4%3D
```

There's nothing wrong with storing each file with a unique name. If you set the correct headers on the file, any downloads can still have the original name. eg `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myimage.jpg;`

---

For listing a buckets contents you would use the APIs [GetBucket](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTBucketGET.html) command. I find it easier to use the [SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/code) for any access via the API.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a pain to search or do things in parallel over bucket objects as amazon lists everything lexicographically (the only way currently supported). The problem with using random IDs is that all of it would be written to the same block storage and you cannot do search in parallel to optimize.

Here is an interesting article on performance improvements. I use it for my work and see significant difference in high load.
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event.html